# Why do my new branches in Android Studio automatically merge to the previous branches?

Tags: android-studio

I am using the Android Studio functionality to manage my branches/commits etc.

I have the master branch which is reserved for final versions, then I have my development branch and then I open new branches for any features I want to work on.

I've just noticed that my changes in my new branches are automatically merged into my previous branch.
For example, if I'm on the development branch then create a new branch "Image gallery" and add something, when I go back to the development branch, that thing I've added is already there!
This beats the whole purpose of using branches, what is going on? Did I click anything I shouldn't have clicked?

Comment: I think you are not commit changes which has done in Image gallery branch. if you just change the branch to development without commiting it show the changes in local.

Comment: @IshanFernando you are right! Thank you! Didn't know that's how it works. Do you want to add this is an answer so I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are not commit the changes which we are done in the feature branch(image branch), it will added to the development branch when we change the branch local. First we need to commit the changes which is done feature branch(image branch). Then we need to change the branch to the development.